# Нужен скрипт, который при добавлении класса active меняет изображение в другом блоке

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Доброго времени суток. Нужен скрипт, который при добавлении класса active к елементу owl-carousel 2 будет менять изображение в другом блоке. Есть слайдер и кнопки, при наведении кнопки показуют превю следующей странички (скриншот ниже )б нуджно чтобы при смене слайдов, менялись так же картинки, которые в кнопках.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как вариант вешаешь на слайды data-id="path/to/image", ловишь current слайд берешь его data-id и подставляешь .css({'background': data-id current slide}); как-то так

Comment: @LieutenantJimDangle, а можете как то попроще пояснить?)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот у вас создается карусель. Добавляем сюда ссылку на функцию, которая будет вызываться при любых изменениях в карусели:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    ....
    onСhanged: callback
});
```

А сама функция будет такого вида:

```
function callback(event) {
    /*event.item.index содержит номер текущего слайда*/
    switch ( event.item.index ) {
      case 0:
        /* настраиваем изображения если первый слайд*/
        break;
      case 1:
         /* настраиваем изображения если второй слайд*/
        break;
      ....
    }
}
```

Надеюсь, уж сами картинки поменять сможете.